# Excel File opening in browser not calling Excel

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

I am calling a function to return an Excel file and it is not opening in Excel, instead it is opening another tab in the browser.  Here is my view:

```
 @model InventoryControl.Models.AdminModel

 <div>
@if (Model.TableCounts != null)
{
    <table class="table_body">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.TableCountModel.TableName)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.TableCountModel.Rows)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.TableCountModel.Count)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>x.TableCountModel.Size)</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model.TableCounts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.TableName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Rows
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Count
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Size
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
else
{
    <p><i>No data available</i></p>
}
  </div>
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Excel", "Excel")
</div>
```

Here is my controller function:

```
 public void Excel()
    {
        var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();
        grid.DataSource = ReportsRepository.TableCounts();
        grid.DataBind();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Dispositon", "attachment; filename=TableCounts.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        grid.RenderControl(htw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
 }
```

I have looked in vain for an example that works and cannot find something that does.

If I make this change:

```
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Dispositon", "attachment; filename=TableCounts.xlsx");
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

The file save/open dialog is fired but it says it is Excel 2003 format and the filename it says is "Excel".

Comment: CSV files are *not* Excel files. There's no reason for the client's computer to use Excel to read it, unless Excel is the default program for this.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - true, but most are here.  Mine is set that way and it does not open in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't create an Excel file, it creates a CSV file. The content type isn't Excel-specific either. A browser may decide that Excel is the appropriate application to open this text file or not.

Even if the browser selects Excel, opening the file may fail, eg if the client's locale uses `,` as a decimal separator. This is common in European countries. In this case Excel expect `;` as the field separator and may open the CSV as a single text block.

Instead of trying to trick the browser into opening a CSV in Excel, create a real Excel file using a library like [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com). EPPlus is available as a [Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) so it's very easy to add it to your project.

The library's documentation contains an [article](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) on how to use it in Web applications. Once you remove the formatting code from the example, the code is very simple:

```
   private void DumpExcel(DataTable tbl)
    {
        using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            //Create the worksheet
            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Demo");

            //Load the datatable into the sheet, starting from cell A1. Print the column names on row 1
            ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(tbl, true);


            //Write it back to the client
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=ExcelDemo.xlsx");
            Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        }
    }
```

Excel files are compressed which means that sending the file to the client will be a lot faster, especially for large files

Comment: I've added that package to my project and my controller does not recognize the ExcelPackage - what do I include?

Comment: Add `using OfficeOpenXml;`

Answer (score 0):

Check your default program for opening csv files and set it to Excel.

Comment: Mine is set that way and it does not open in excel.